# Create select box from ul-li-menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, html-lists

I want to create responsive menu for mobile and touch devices, like Bootstrap Menu.
I wrote this code on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7GL4/)

How do I separate parents from their children?
or How do I separate Menu items from their submenu?
like:

```
##Internet
-submenu
...
```

in my select box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable like this:

```
   var prefix = $(this).closest('ul').hasClass("sub-menu") ? "- " : "";
```

then append it to your code:

```
$('#RESPONSIVE-MENU').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", $(this).attr('href')).text(
   prefix +

   $(this).html()

)); });
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/v7GL4/1/)

UPDATE:

A dynamic (and better) approach can be this one:

```
var prefix = "",
    x = $(this).parents('ul').length;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) prefix = prefix + "-";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7GL4/2/

Comment: This is very good,Thank you.But If `ul li` nested 3 level it's not working... or if not exist `.sub-menu` it's not working...

Comment: thank you too.I find my answer 6sec Sooner :) But i accept Your Answer

Answer (score 1):

I find comprehensive way to arrive my answer...
pumpkinzzz and... thank you!

```
$('<select/>', {id: 'RESPONSIVE-MENU'}).appendTo('.navmen-topmenu-container');

var options = '<option selected>Go to...</option>';
$('.navmen-topmenu-container').find('a').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text(),
        depth = $(this).parent().parents('ul').length,
        depthChar = '',
        i = 1;
    for (i; i < depth; i++) { depthChar += '&ndash;&nbsp;'; }
    options += '<option>' + depthChar + text + '</option>';
});
$('#RESPONSIVE-MENU').append(options).appendTo('.navmen-topmenu-container');
$('#RESPONSIVE-MENU').change(function(){if($(this).val() !=''){window.location.href=$(this).val();event.preventDefault();}});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/v7GL4/3/

```
 $('.navmen-topmenu-container').append('<select id="RESPONSIVE-MENU"><option value="">Nav Menu</option></select>');

     $('#navmen-topmenu li a').each(function(){
         if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('sub-menu')) {
             $('#RESPONSIVE-MENU').append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"> - ' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
         } else {
             $('#RESPONSIVE-MENU').append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">##' + $(this).text().toUpperCase() + '</option>');
         }
    });

    $('#RESPONSIVE-MENU').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() !=''){
            window.location.href=$(this).val();event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```